# Unexpected character after line continuation when running python for Kmeans

Tags: python, ubuntu, apache-spark, k-means

I am implementing `K-Means` in `Spark` and when I try to run my script using `spark-submit Kmeans.py` I keep getting the error `unexpected character after line continuation`. I am using the backslash for line continuation but I don't see how I am using it wrong. I will post my algorithm below.

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext, Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
import json
import os

conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Phone Book - Country Look up") \
        .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
        .getOrCreate()

dataset = spark.read.format("libsvm") \
        .load("/home/jay/Assignment6/Input.txt")

dataset.show(200)
dataset.printSchema()

kmeans = KMeans().setK(2).setSeed(1)
model = kmeans.fit(dataset)

var1 = model.computeCost(dataset)
print("Within Set Sum of Squared Errors =" + str(var1))

centers = model.clusterCenters()
print("Cluster centers: ")
for center in centers:
        print(center)
```

Comment: on which line is the error `unexpected character after line continuation` ?

Comment: on line 15       .builder   \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Unexpected character after line continuation character* nearly always means you have a space after the `\`, which is of course hard to see. If it is reported on line 15 the problem is probably on line 14. You can make such problems go away by dropping the continuation characters and enclosing the expression in parentheses:

```
spark =(SparkSession 
        .builder 
        .appName("Phone Book - Country Look up") 
        .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") 
        .getOrCreate())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo: `.builder` should be `.builder()`.